# WCF Service can't return struct from another class?

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, struct

So I am currently writing a new WCF Service, which should return a Struct when one of it's functions is called. The struct is held in a shared class since it is used in others areas of the program.

The struct looks as follows (Note, it is inside a VB.Net class, some of the project is in C#):

```
<DataContract()>
Public Structure WrapperResults
    <DataMember()>
    Dim Success As Boolean
    <DataMember()>
    Dim ErrorMessage As String
End Structure
```

Now in the WCF Service I have set up I have a simple test function that looks like this:

```
public class TFXEmailProcessor : Wrapper
    {
        public MQShared.Functions.WrapperResults CallWrapper(string AppName, string Password, string ConfigXML)
        {
            MQShared.Functions.WrapperResults results = new MQShared.Functions.WrapperResults();

            results.ErrorMessage = "TFX Test";
            results.Success = true;

            return results;
        }
    }
```

And in another class I have added a reference to my WCF Service and attempt to call it like:

```
Dim myBinding As New BasicHttpBinding()
Dim endpointAddress As New EndpointAddress(WP.MyWrapper(x).WrapperURL)
Dim SR As New WrapperService.WrapperClient(myBinding, endpointAddress)

Dim WrapResults As MQShared.Functions.WrapperResults = SR.CallWrapper(AppName, Password, WP.MyWrapper(x).ConfigXML)
```

However the SR.CallWrapper function is highlighted by Intellisense and I get the error `Value of type 'FunctionsWrapperResults' cannot be converted to 'Functions.WrapperResults'` (Note the missing period in FunctionsWrapperResults)

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Try to implement StructLayout above your Datacontract.

Comment: @Nagu_R Tried using StructLayout.Auto but that did not fix the issue.

Comment: I believe, you would have created 2 set of Wrapper results class and deleted one of those/renamed. If the referenced assemblies have the same assembly identity, then remove or replace one of the file references so that there is only a single file reference.

Comment: @Nagu_R I did have a WrapperResults struct in the TXFEmailProcessor class but I have now moved it to the shared class so that several classes can access it. I only have one reference to the TXFEmailProcessor class (where I attempt to call the CallWrapper function) so I'm not sure what to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this problem just by letting the compiler work out the return value instead of specifically declaring it as

```
Dim WrapResults As MQShared.Functions.WrapperResults
```

I now simply declare the function call as:

```
Dim WrapResults = SR.CallWrapper(AppName, Password, WP.MyWrapper(x).ConfigXML)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to call WCF service. **Proxy** and **Channel**.

In Proxy, you can add WCF service to your project with **Add Service Reference ...** In this way, proxy classes generated automatically. You can't use your shared classes. Because, shared classes generated again as proxy.

If you can use shared classes, you must choose Channel way. In channel, add ServiceContact (interface) and DataContract to the client project.

I use C#

```
    var address = new EndpointAddress("..."); // Service address
    var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(); // Binding type

    var channel = ChannelFactory<IService>.CreateChannel(binding, address);

    MQShared.Functions.WrapperResults WrapResults = channel.CallWrapper(string AppName, string Password, string ConfigXML);
```